# Use of ORA_ROWSCN to find current and immediate previous transaction

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I have table TEST_TABLE having 3 columns COL1(Number), COL2(Varchar), COL3(Date).
I want to find the result of the below query in an anonymous block for two different transactions. One for the current transaction and the other for the immediately previous transaction. How to do it using SCN?

```
    BEGIN
    Select col3 into v_curr_date from test_table where col1=123; --Current 
    uncommitted Transaction

    Select col3 into v_prev_date from test_table where col1=123; --How to 
    modify this query to find for immediately Previous committed Transaction.

    END ;
```

Comment: I don't see the point in committed transaction with a `SELECT ..INTO` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Below one will gives you the latest committed date happened on a table. SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP takes as an argument a number that evaluates to a system change number (SCN), and returns the approximate timestamp associated with that SCN. So modify your query accordingly.

```
     DECLARE
     v_prev_date  date;
     BEGIN
     Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) into v_prev_date 
     from test_table where col1=123;
     dbms_output.put_line(v_prev_date  );
    end;
```